# Laravel Backpack PermissionManager in crud

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

They are at the first experiences with laravel 5 and backpack.
I installed the backpack permission manager and I have a questions:

I created permissions / roles and created two users.

1. in my sidebar_content.blade.php I use conditions correctly

```
    @role('Admin')
    <!-- Users, Roles, Permissions -->
    <li class="nav-item nav-dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="nav-icon la la-users"></i> Authentication</a>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('user') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-user"></i> <span>Users</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('role') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-id-badge"></i> <span>Roles</span></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{ backpack_url('permission') }}"><i class="nav-icon la la-key"></i> <span>Permissions</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="...
    <li class="...
    @role('Magazzino1')
    <li class="...
    @endrole
    @role('Magazzino2')
    <li class="...
    @endrole
```

but if i know the example routing
/ admin / user / create I access the page (also for Edit / delete etc ...)

How can I allow access only if the user in use is with the "Admin" role?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Backpack uses backpack auth, while @role, @can etc directives by default use the laravel auth.

You can accomplish the same by using `backpack_user()->hasRole('your_role')` or by telling laravel to use the backpack auth instead of the default one.

Please read the PermissionManager package `README` and you have an example there on how to to achieve the second scenario if that's your desire. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager (it's the `7` point on the README).

Cheers